# Issues with glCompileShader

Tags: opengl-es, emulation, mali

I got issue compiling my shaders in Windows 8. When the application compiles the shader by calling glCompileShader, the debugger throws the following compile error:

> 'malisc' is not recognized as an internal or ex ternal command,

Apperently it's calling the Mali offline compiler. It's the first time this happens to me. I'm using the OpenGLES 2.0 mali emulator.

My Graphic card is GeForce GT 640, but I don't know if this is relevant. Why is this command is getting called? and why it doesn't let my compile my shaders? How can I solve this?

Comment: What version of Mali OpenGL ES Emulator are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Forget it, I've already solve it. I roll back my GeForce driver from 340.xx to 331.65. Thanks anyway.